# Anim notifies not working in unreal engine

Tags: animation, unreal-5

[image]. I think I have setup things needed to fireoff a custom AnimNotify, but, for some reason, custom notifies don't fire off. The premade notifies for playing sounds etc, fire off okay. But, this notify is something I made using `Add Notify > New Notify` . This event seems to be available in the character's blueprint which should mean the setup wasn't improper. Yet, the message doesn't get displayed in the screen. Am I missing to do something?